# Labview: error 1057 when casting to more specific object

Tags: oop, casting, labview

I have two classes in C# compiled into a library to be imported into a LabView project.

```
    public class Upper
    {
        public sbyte Signed8 { get; set; }

        public char Unicode16 { get; set; }
        public short Signed16 { get; set; }
        public int Signed32 { get; set; }
        public long Signed64 { get; set; }
```

```
    public int UpperDoSomething() { return Signed32; }
}
```

and

public class Lower : Upper
    {
        public byte Unsigned8 { get; set; }
        public ushort Unsigned16 { get; set; }
        public uint Unsigned32 { get; set; }
        public ulong Unsigned64 { get; set; }

public uint LowerDoSomething() { return Unsigned32; }
}

I keep getting error 1057:
"Type mismatch: Object cannot be cast to the specific type"

To spare anyone from downloading the file, analyzing the component "to more specific class":

- Upper is connected to reference class
- An unitialized Lower class is connected to target class
- A property node is connected to specific class reference
- (side note) for anyone who downloads the vi, there is a property connected to an indicator to not have any loose wires

Comment: [link to download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15OX_92yc4327SxlA85SCyh9CwAU1YdTP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the constructor of the Upper, then trying to case it to a Lower, which it isn't an instance of.

The tsc block (and generally casting to a descendant in OOP) is useful when you've passed subclass instances through code treating it as the parent class, but then have an operation that requires the subclass type. It has to have been created as an instance of the subclass though.